# Self-Contained Application Packaging for java swing maven project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, ant, self-contained

**I want to make a self-contained package (including jre 8).**
I have a `Maven` project developed in `Eclipse`.

I have read that `JavaFX` has support for building towards different platforms (Windows, Mac, Linux).

What is the best way forward? I know there is an `eclipseFx` plugin and there is a `maven fx` plugin as well. This confuses me since `JavaFx` uses ant script for building.

Maybe I should use some other tool, like `launch4j`?